# Python 3 pandas directory search for a string in filename

Tags: csv, pandas, import, filenames, python-3.5

Hello again StackExchange!

Attempting to print all files in a directory but this time I only want to print all of the .csv files that have the string ..."AMX_error"...csv somewhere in the filename.  I have the "all .csv" working, but am missing that bit of search logic.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Experiment\'

#Following command to search for string in the filename
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv") & (search filename 'AMX_error' = true)

for filename in allFiles:
    print(filename)

#rest of code..
```

What is the notation to search for a string in a filename?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a reason for filtering the files first, you can simply check that the string of interest is in the filename while you're in the for loop.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Experiment'

#Following command to search for string in the filename
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

for filename in allFiles:
    if 'AMX_error' in filename:
        print(filename)
```

Comment: Never thought to use an if-then loop to identify specific filenames.  That works!  Should be able to get a handle on my nuanced (by filename) dataset.